# How can I check identity in 1 column in SQL query?

Tags: sql

I need a way to get true-false reply from SQL query that say to me: value in one column are the same or not?

Comment: The value in a column is the same as what? Different rows or another column?

Comment: How would you handle different datatypes? Would a varchar column value of "1" equal money column of 1.0? Would a null value equal null in another?

Comment: All fields in column have the same value

Comment: @RuslanBorovilov They all have the same value? Easy `create function test() return true`

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I mean if all fields in column have the same value return true

Comment: exemple:
`stuff
3
3
3
3`

return true

`stuff
3
3
3
4`

return false

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What do you mean "All fields in column"? Are you storing a delimited list in a single column? If not what is your table structure (column names)? What semantics for NULL?

Comment: @MartinSmith I have abstract RDBMS and table and it does not matter, I need the simplest solution. Table hasn`t NULLs. 
I have 1 column in table.
I want to get true, if all values in this column is the same. Not more.

Comment: @RuslanBorovilov: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Consider visiting all sections of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). That will improve your experience here and you will earn a badge as a bonus. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page is also worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, if there are no null values in the column. Null values in the column are ignored by this solution.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN MIN(Column1) <> MAX(Column1) THEN 'FALSE' 
        ELSE 'TRUE' 
    END 
FROM MyTable
```

I tested this with SQL Server when the datatype of Column1 is varchar and int.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking to compare two strings? In MySQL, that would be [STRCMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp).

Update:

Based upon feedback in replies to my answer, the following should work in most SQL variants.

```
SELECT count(0)=1 GROUP BY column
```

This will group rows by their value of column, and then count how many groups there are. If there is only one group, all rows have the same value for column.

Comment: I mean if all fields in column have the same value return true

Comment: Do you mean "if all columns in a row have the same value", or "all rows in a column have the same value"?

Comment: all rows in a column have the same value